# Is there a term for a non-Jewish friend of the Jews?

Tags: words, gentiles

I saw a related, unanswered question but it was specific to honorable *deceased* non-Jews.

I'm wondering if there is a Yiddish term in Judaism for someone who may be close friends with many Jews, who knows a lot about Jewish culture, but who is not Jewish (or some definition close to that).

Any term that would discern them from a random *goyim*?

Comment: I can think of a few terms in family resemblance with this concept: Ger toshav; chassid umot ha-olam/Righteous Among the Nations (its difference from the previous is discussed here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ger_toshav#Modern_times_and_views ); yireh Shomayim (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God-fearer); ger hashaar; Noahide/Ben Noach. Further afield: zera Yisroel

Comment: @SAH you should add that as an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The English term philosemitism may possibly be translated into Hebrew as אוהבי ישראל but there is no specific term in Yiddish for this concept. There does not appear to be a specific usage for *friendliness*. However, there are terms for the unusual cases shown below.

This seems to be what the Yad Vashem lists as [Righteous Among the Nations](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/righteous-among-the-nations) or *Righteous Gentiles* which in Hebrew might be Chasidei Umos Haolam (Righteous of the nations of the world)

This (as an example) is used for those gentiles who rescued Jews from the Nazis during world war II such as [Chiune Sugihara](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/chiune-sugihara)

Comment: This isn't Yiddish (as the question asks) nor is it about having friends and knowing about Judaism. The title is reserved for those who "risked their lives to save Jews" according to the site you linked to. The chasidei Umos Haolam are labeled based on Noachide practice from what I have read (http://www.noachide.org.uk/html/chasidei_umot_haolam.html) not friendliness.

Comment: Yes that is true. However, that is the closest that I could come to separating from random gentiles. In English philosemitism may or may not have a Hebrew translation. I will expand this.

Comment: If someone finds something closer to what I was looking for I will definitely mark their answer as the solution, but this is still useful to me. Thank you both.